# How to change default local discovery port for Apache Ignite?

Tags: java, ignite

How to change the default local discovery port for Apache Ignite?
I am looking to change the default from 47500 to something else but not from the code side. Instead of JVM argument.
We use Ignite as a cache server in our application.

IgniteConfig

```java
@Bean
  public Ignite igniteInstance(JdbcIpFinderDialect ipFinderDialect, DataSource dataSource) {
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setGridLogger(new Slf4jLogger());
    cfg.setMetricsLogFrequency(0);
    TcpDiscoverySpi discoSpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi()
        .setIpFinder(new TcpDiscoveryJdbcIpFinder(ipFinderDialect).setDataSource(dataSource)
            .setInitSchema(initialiseIgniteSchema));
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoSpi);
    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfigurations.toArray(new CacheConfiguration[0]));
    return Ignition.start(cfg);
  }
```

Comment: Why not inject a system property as a field here, use it with .setLocalPort()? Are you using that Spring bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per comment from @alamar I was able to parameterise port with System property defaulting it to 47500 if not provided

```java
@Value("${localPort:47500}")
private long localPort;
```

and assiging that to IgniteConfig when instantiating engine

```java
cfg.setLocalPort(localPort);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setLocalPort(int locPort)`.

Comment: Thanks, that might work but as I mentioned in question, I am looking to change that through jvm argument not by updating code at the moment.